# How to call stored procedure in ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, t-sql

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblDepartment]
(
    [departmentId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblDepartment] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([departmentId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblUser]
(
    [userId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [address] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [state] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [salary] [bigint] NULL,
    [departmentId] [int] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblUser] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([userId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblUser] WITH CHECK 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY([departmentId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[tblDepartment] ([departmentId])
GO
```

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[tblDepartment_insertUpdate]
    @userId int =0,
    @name nvarchar(50) ,
    @state nvarchar (50),
    @address nvarchar(500),
    @departmentId int ,
    @result nvarchar(50) output
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@userId = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tblUser (name, address, state, departmentId)
        VALUES (@name, @address, @state, @departmentId)

        IF (@@identity > 0)
           SET @result = 'Record save successfully'
        ELSE
           SET @result = 'Record not saved!'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE tblUser 
        SET name = @name,
            address = @address,
            state = @state,
            departmentId = @departmentId
        WHERE userId = @userId

        SET @result = 'Record Updated !'
    END
END
```

What I have tried:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostEmpDetails(string name, int departmentId, string address, int salary, string state, int userId) {
  if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
      return BadRequest(ModelState);
  }

  // by using own stored procedure
  var spName = new SqlParameter("@name", name);
  var spState = new SqlParameter("@state", state);
  var spAddress = new SqlParameter("@address", address);
  var spDepartmentId = new SqlParameter("@departmentId", departmentId);
  var spUser = new SqlParameter("@userId", userId);

  var spOut = new SqlParameter {
   ParameterName = "@result",
    SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar,
    Size = 100,
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
  };

  var user = eContext.Database.SqlQuery < tbluser > ("exec  tblDepartment_insertUpdate @userId,@name,@state,@address,@departmentId, @result out ",
   spUser, spName, spState, spAddress, spDepartmentId, spOut
  ).ToList < tbluser > ();
  return Ok(user);
 }
```

I want to use my stored procedure in ASP.NET MVC for crud operations in a WebAPI project, but in post method, I get an error. Please suggest a solution

This is the error I get:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'EntityTestModel.tblUser'. A member of the type, 'userId', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Comment: 1. why are you take every single field as parameter not use Modelbinding.

Comment: how to use modelbinding

Comment: The question is unclear (and there is no actual question), and doesn't just contain the basics of the subject. Please rephrase the question more clearly and fix your layout so that it becomes easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: This would be better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "how to use modelbinding". Take any MVC / Web API tutorial, it'll show you an example. But basically something like `public IHttpActionResult PostEmpDetails(UserViewModel user)`. And then you have a `public class UserViewModel {` etc. within your solution which contains all the properties. Then you can pass that object around as one entity instead of multiple properties. if the caller submits the data in the right format then .NET will create an instance of UserViewModel from it without any effort from you. TBH this is a general principle of Object-Oriented code, not just MVC etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create Model

[image]

2. Posting Data to APIController from PostMan

[image]

3. APIController View

[image]

Note :- Remove your Database Saving code from Controller and place it in Different Class Libary.

Comment: Thank's Saineshwar